# What is the identity number for exponentiation/logarithm?

Tags: exponentiation, symmetry, binary-operations

If the identity number of the addition/subtraction pair of operations is 0.

and the identity number of the multiplication/division pair of operations is 1.

what is the identity number of the exponentiation/logarithm pair of operations?

Comment: Do you mean to consider $a^b$ with $^$ as your operation and $a$ and $b$ as the inputs?  If so, what makes you think this should have an identity?

Comment: Also, subtraction does not have an identity, nor does division (at least not two-sided).

Comment: well, I don't know if it has an identity. And I don't know how to find out. That's why I'm asking

Comment: what do you mean by a two sided identity?

Comment: Assuming you are working with real numbers (this isn't clear), there is no element $a$ such that $x-a=x$ and $a-x=x$ for all $x$.  You only get it on one side, which is $x-a=x$ for all $x$ (with the winner being $a=0$, obviously).

Comment: If $a^b=a$ then b=1. but $a^b=b$, then a is not a constant.

Comment: I see, when you consider subtraction as an operation, there really is no identity. I was considering subtraction as a special case of addition by a negative number

Comment: Problems are that exponentiation is not commutative i.e $a^b\neq b^a$ so there's only one side identity i.e $a^1=a$. While for the other side there's no identity that works for all real numbers in general. Exponentiation in terms of properties is pretty poor, no associativity, no commutivity etc.

Comment: @kingW3 yeah! I was wondering if there might be an identity in another realm besides the real numbers? maybe in the complex numbers, or the surreal numbers?

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion above, its clear that exponentiation does not have an identity in the real numbers.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element#Definitions) says that there are left identities (where e*a=a) and right identities (where a*e=a), and that if a single number is both its called a two sided identity,and is accepted as the identity element for that operation.

The problem with exponentiation is that there is only a right identity (a^1=a) and there is no left identity. So while you might be tempted to call **1** the identity of exponentiation, its just on one side and does not count for both.

So, at least in the real numbers, exponentiation does not have an identity.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804451/is-there-a-reason-mathematical-operations-come-in-pairs?rq=1) for a clear explanation of why its a mistake to assume that exponentiation only has one inverse operation (the other is rooting)

And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672667/a-more-symmetric-exponentiation?rq=1) for a little tour on MAKING an operation like exponentiation that has an identity.